# Passing PDF with servlets

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, request, response

I am sending a request to a servlet that is viewed something like `http://url:8080/getDocument?docName=doc.pdf` I am not too sure how the servlet that sent out the request will handle the PDF file when returned and then send the response back to my web page for the user to then just download or save.

I already have code that sends back XML documents and that is handled properly. Would I be doing a similar method?

1) How does a servlet send a pdf file over the network?

2) How does the receiving servlet handle the pdf?

3) After receiving the servlet how can I pass that on to the user to download or view?

Comment: In order to know whether you should do something *similar*, please post also the relevant code sending XML documents to the `ServletOutputStream`

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you trying to send the file from the browser to the server, or from the server to the browser?

Comment: I send a request from the web-server to another server. The web-server is receiving the PDF. The web-server then sends the pdf to the browser to be downloaded. So its going Browser request -> web-server -> other server -> PDF -> other server -> web-server -> browser. I didn't write the whole system, that's just what it is.

Comment: Given that XML (a text based format) just works fine for you, perhaps you're treating the data as characters instead of bytes? Perhaps you just need to use `OutputStream`/`InputStream` instead of `Writer`/`Reader` in the sending/receiving code? (which should work as good on XML documents by the way).

Answer (score 1):

If the response you are sending is a pdf document you should add

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf")
```

in your servlet code.

Comment: I need to be able to send the document too. With json I convert a hashmap then do `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); response.setContentType("application/json"); response.getWriter().write(json);` But for a PDF wouldnt I need to do something different?

Comment: Usually you set the contentType and encoding, and then write the contents of the file (pdf in your case). Your pdf will not be stored in a Hashmap, so depending  on where it is, you will need different code to access the bytes.